# Joomla site crash after youtube video upload

Tags: joomla, youtube, crash

yesterday I uploaded a video from youtube in an article in my joomla site using the editor  TinyMCE, I used the video icon and I inserted the youtube URL. Then I save the article and from that point the site is inaccessible. Every page print the same error on a white 
background:

```
username: 
pw:
host: gdata.youtube.com
port: 
path: /feeds/users/Fondazione Gaber/uploads
query: orderby=rating&max-results=50&format=5
fragment:
```

Everything is disappeared.

The youtube video I inserted was wrong because it wasn't a video url but a compilation url.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qWHSDOwBFD0&list=UUeERCnBcsmhHvunRHnR0Rmw&index=1

It seems that joomla tries to make a query on a list of video, but it is too large (>200 videos), and the limit is 50.

Everything is very strange because the video wasn't in the homepage but in a subsection.
I tried to delete the article and empty the trash without result.

I tried with debug and the php page index.php give the message when the function

```
// Render the application.
$app->render();
```

is invoked.

The backend works normally.

Comment: I have never seen such error.  Is your site in

1. /feeds/users/Fondazione Gaber/uploads

or 
2. /feeds/users/Fondazione Gaber ?

if 2. then what is the uploads folder? Joomla doesn't have one. Did you try renaming it? Maybe the issue is not directly related to the video upload, could you provide us with the url?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the article.

If you cannot access back-end, try to delete that article from databese with PHPMyAdmin tool or alike.
Table: #__content

But make back-up first.

I would recommend to use Youtube Gallery extension, it can show one video or read entire channel to get all videos.

You place the youtube link into "Video List" box and it will recognize it's type automatically.